GitHub Desktop is not signing GPG key automatically
After following the GitHub guide for generating a new GPG key, telling git about my key and adding the key to my GitHub account, I get the following error in every commit on GitHub Desktop:

I also tried setting the path of the gpg program in .gitconfig to
[gpg]
    program = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuPG\\bin\\gpg.exe"

However, if I try to open the repo in Command Prompt or commit directlly with git, it works and allows me to enter the passphrase and commit successfully. I have correctly installed gpg4win and I'm on Windows 10. Can anyone help me here?
